# eval() is not working

Tags: javascript, eval

So I try build my own Javascript calculator as an exercise. Unfortunately when I try to use the `eval()` function with "=" button click to convert string into result, for example "2+2*2", nothing happens. Here's my code:

```
var draw = document.getElementById("result");

function calc(x) {
 draw.innerHTML += x;
 if (x === '=') {
    draw.innerHTML = eval(draw.innerHTML);
 } else if (x === 'c') {
    draw.innerHTML = '0';
 } else if (x === 'sqrt') {
    draw.innerHTML = Math.sqrt(eval(draw.innerHTML));
 } else if (x === 'pow') {
    draw.innerHTML = Math.pow(eval(draw.innerHTML));
 }
}
```

Comment: Maybe draw is not a string, but the "result" element itself. What do you think ?

Comment: m**cv**e -> [mcve] ?!

Comment: @alain yes. But why should this discovery help?!

Comment: NB: `Math.pow` needs two arguments. Maybe you intended the second argument to be 2, so that it squares the given number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
draw.innerHTML += x;
```

means if e.g. your string is `2*2` and you call

```
calc("sqrt")
```

the draws content will be

```
 "2*2sqrt"
```

and thats not a valid expression, therefore the `eval` will fail. You may want to only concat if its not an operation:

```
 function calc(x) {
  if (x === '=') {
    return draw.innerHTML = eval(draw.innerHTML);
  } else if (x === 'c') {
     return draw.innerHTML = '0';
  } else if (x === 'sqrt') {
     return draw.innerHTML = Math.sqrt(eval(draw.innerHTML));
  } else if (x === 'pow') {
     return draw.innerHTML = Math.pow(eval(draw.innerHTML),2);
  }
  draw.innerHTML += x;
 }
```

That can be beautified with an object as a lookup table:

```
const result = n => eval(n),
           sqrt = n => Math.sqrt(eval(n)),
           pow = n => Math.pow(eval(n),2),
           default = (n, add) => n + add;

function calc(in){
  draw.innerHTML = ({"=":result, sqrt, pow}[in] || default)(draw.innerHTML, in);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But your solution still leaves "=", "sqrt", "pow" in the result HTML element after calculations. Maybe I should just use separate functions for those evaluations.